# git updates file modification time on rebase even if the file didn't change

Tags: git

When I do git rebase, if there was no change the files will keep their modification time.
However, this is not the case if a file has local changes - its modification time is updated to the current time, even if there was no change because of the rebase (which contradicts git FAQ "Git sets the current time as the timestamp on every file it modifies, but only those.").

This is extremely annoying if such a local change (e.g. a mere debug printing) is in your makefile or cmakefile - the whole source tree is being rebuilt because of the updated file timestamp.

Is there any way to preserve the modification time of the locally changed files if the rebase didn't result in any change in those files (for example, because there were simply no changes on the branch I'm rebasing to since the last rebase)?

I'm using git 2.18.0, if it matters

Comment: I didn't double check docs, but from my understanding `git rebase` means re-writing history and that should result in new timestamps in my opinion. Why do you need `rebase`? Also, I don't understand why would you have to rebase makefiles (often)? If it is a one time event, just accept that you have to rebuild once, because you chose `rebase`. If it occurs on a regular basis, question why it has to be `rebase` over `merge`.

Comment: @tomwaitforitmy I update the whole tree, not just the makefile, it's buried deep enough.

Comment: @tomwaitforitmy As to "why rebase" - I want my feature branch to grow from the origin master branch - so `git fetch && git rebase origin/master` gives me exactly what I want: if any new commits appeared at the remote origin/master, my feature branch will be rebased on top of them and will be clean and linear with no intermingling commits (and I don't need to checkout/update the master branch locally too, which is quite a time saver).
This all works perfectly for years, except the updated modification time of the locally modified files on each rebase.

Comment: I still don't fully understand why you have to rebase on a regular basis. The CI/CD recommendation is to develop features as small ship-able increments and merge at least two times a day. So you can question if your feature branches have to live long enough to require rebase. I don't know if there is any solution for the timestamps, but you could change your merging strategy if your concern regarding timestamps is very pressing. It might be choosing pros and cons.

Comment: `if such a local change (e.g. a mere debug printing) is in your makefile` - perhaps you need to either commit this change and revert/remove it when it's time to merge the feature branch, or find any other workflow were you don't have uncommitted local changes. It'd be helpful to add more details to the question about your problem, for example how does the timestamp of the (c)makefile affect things? Readers shouldn't need to know/guess, and these details may yield more relevant alternatives.

Comment: `for example, because there were simply no changes on the branch I'm rebasing to since the last rebase` so you _do_ have changes in your branch history for that file in addition to the uncommitted change? Please clarify by editing the question (preferably by showing or demonstrating the commit history).